# Set operations in RavenDB

Tags: c#, ravendb

I read [this article](http://ravendb.net/documentation/set-based) on ravendb set operations, but it didn't show me exactly how to update a set of documents via C#.  I would like to update a field on all documents that match a certain criteria.  Or to put it another way, I would like to take this C# and make it more efficient:

```
var session = db.GetSession();
foreach(var data in session.Query<Data>().Where(d => d.Color == "Red"))
{
    data.Color = "Green";
    session.Store(data);
}
session.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/faq/denormalized-updates

First parameter is the name of the index you wish to update.
Second parameter is the index query which lets you specify your where clause. The syntax for the query is the lucene syntax (http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/queryparsersyntax.html). Third parameter is the update clause. Fourth parameter is if you want stale results.

```
documentStore.DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex("DataByColor",
    new IndexQuery
    {
        Query = "Color:red"
    }, new[]
    {
            new PatchRequest
            {
                Type = PatchCommandType.Set,
                Name = "Color",
                Value = "Green"
            }
    },
    allowStale: false);
```

Comment: Is there documentation somewhere to explain the query syntax?  Specifically, how do I find all documents where some field equals some value?

Comment: @jake-pearson I modified my answer to reflect your question. Hope that helps.

Comment: Does it matter what I use for the query name?

Comment: Yes, that's the name of the index on which you want to query. See https://s3.amazonaws.com/daily-builds/RavenDBMythology-11.pdf chapter 5 for more information on creating indexes.

Comment: I hope sometime soon, we could use the normal dynamic query functionality to define which documents to do a set operation on.